# terminal emulator vs terminal

Tags: command-line, kernel, emulation

I am a having a little trouble understanding the difference between running the terminal emulator from the GUI (gnome) and booting straight into the terminal. I have been a system/network administrator for a little over 10 years and I am very familiar with terminal emulation and how it works on a Windows platform, however I was told by a Linux "engineer" that running the terminal emulator from the GUI (as root) would not grant the proper permissions to edit the kernel source code. He said you need to boot to the console and login as root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Booting straight into the terminal means running in the text console. Technically, this console (/dev/console, /dev/tty1, /dev/tty2 and the likes) is just provided by another terminal emulator.

Real terminals like the famous VT100 used to be connected to computer through serial lines but are now essentially history.

About the kernel editing restriction, I guess you misunderstood what was told by the Linux engineer. Obviously, nothing prevents you to edit a file whatever the terminal emulator used. However, if you want to see console messages while experimenting with a custom kernel, that makes more sense.

Comment: As a little addendum, terminal emulators in the GUI are in most cases not virtual terminals, but pseudo terminal slaves (PTS). The number of virtual terminals you can use concurrently on a machine is fixed. You very rarely need for example 64 virtual terminals at the same time, but there is a limit ;) A PTS behaves for almost any purposes like a virtual terminal, but it doesn't occupy a virtual terminal.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck don't confuse the terminal emulators, which are userland pieces of software and the drivers which are behind the devices they are connected to, here the pseudo terminal slaves. The former are emulating a display and a keyboard while the latter are used to interconnect command line programs and the emulators.

Comment: @jlliagre - Are the definitions of a terminal and console the same or do they mean different things? If consoles are provided by another terminal emulator, shouldn't these be /dev/pts1 for example? I have seen VT100 referenced a number of times and if it refers to (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100), it appears to be a strongly coupled video screen, keyboard and computer. If yes, what do you mean by it "used to be connected to [a] computer?

Comment: @Motivated A console used to be **the** main physical device from where operators were interacting with a computer while a terminal was a topological term naming one of the multiple devices connected to a central computer through RS232 serial lines. Terminals, even VT100's were "dumb" and useless when standalone. There was no computer inside, i.e. no operating system, just enough electronics to drive the CRT, the keyboard, the serial line and store the setup.

Comment: @jlliagre - When you say the main physical device, was it part of the computer/server/mainframe? For example, did it feature its own display, mouse and keyboard that were connected to the computer?

Comment: @Motivated In early computers, the console was part of the whole system, initially with switches then with typewriters. Later, the console was a remote device like a VT100. There was no graphics nor mouse on the VT100.

Comment: @jlliagre - Historically was the console limited to switches and typewriters or did it feature video terminals, keyboards and possibly a mouse?

Comment: @Motivated That depends on when you start "history" but computers definitely predate video terminals and mice.

Comment: @jlliagre - In the context of consoles, would these have featured video terminals, keyboards and mice?

Comment: @Motivated Have a look to the [Ferranti Mark 1 console](http://ferut.ca/mark-1/) to get an idea.

Comment: @jlliagre - Thanks. It appears that a console can feature switches and a video terminal. The reason for my question is to understand the use of console and terminal in Linux. If a console is part of a computer and a terminal is a remote device to access a computer, what constitutes a console and terminal in Linux today? For example, you mention that booting straight into a terminal means running a text console. Does that mean that a console runs within a terminal session? Is a terminal emulator only a terminal?

Comment: @jlliagre - I came across your post (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/linux-difference-between-dev-console-dev-tty-and-dev-tty0) however it remains unclear to me. I also read the remaining posts. What is the difference between /dev/tty0 and /dev/tty[1-7]? What does dev/console is a virtual set of devices mean?